# How does file reading work in utf-8 encoding?

Tags: python, utf-8, io

For input text files, I know that .seek and .tell both operate with bytes, usually - that is, .seek seeks a certain number of bytes in relation to a point specified by its given arguments, and .tell returns the number of bytes since the beginning of the file.

My question is: does this work the same way when using other encodings like utf-8? I know utf-8, for example, requires several bytes for some characters.

It would seem that if those methods still deal with bytes when parsing utf-8 files, then unexpected behavior could result (for instance, the cursor could end up inside of a character's multi-byte encoding, or a multi-byte character could register as several characters).

If so, are there other methods to do the same tasks? Especially for when parsing a file requires information about the cursor's position in terms of characters.

On the other hand, if you specify the encoding in the open() function ...

> infile = open(filename, encoding='utf-8')

Does the behavior of .seek and .tell change?

Comment: Good question. Why don't you test it? Save a text file with a 2-3 Chinese characters (use Google Translate to get those), then create a program that opens it, does a seek(1), and then prints from there, and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks! I was had been testing with a file in utf-8 that was populated almost solely with one-byte characters - I hadn't thought of making one especially for the purpose.

Comment: "I am using Python 2.7.3." - no you're not 'cause in python 2.7 open() doesn't have an ``encoding`` keyword argument.

Comment: I saw someone else use the encoding keyword, and so I was wondering if that would affect the way infile's methods worked when it was used. I didn't realize at first that the encoding keyword didn't belong to Python 2.7. I will, however, take out the offending line to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using [`io.open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.open) (not the same as the builtin `open()`), then using text mode gets you an instance of a `io.TextIO`, so this should anwser your question:

> Text I/O over a binary storage (such as a file) is significantly
>   slower than binary I/O over the same storage, because it implies
>   conversions from unicode to binary data using a character codec. This
>   can become noticeable if you handle huge amounts of text data (for
>   example very large log files). Also, TextIOWrapper.tell() and
>   **TextIOWrapper.seek()** are both quite **slow due to the reconstruction
>   algorithm used**.

**NOTE**: You should also be aware, that this still doesn't guarantee that seek() will skip over characters, but rather unicode codepoints (a single character can be composed out of more then one codepoint, for example `ą` can be written as `u'\u0105'` or `u'a\u0328'` - both will print the same character).

Source: http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#id1

Comment: Though if you're using Python 3, `io.open()` is just an alias for the builtin `open()`.

Answer (score 1):

Some experimentation with utf-8 encodings (repeated seeking and printing of .read(1) methods in a file with lots of multi-byte characters) revealed that yes, .seek() and .read() do behave differently in utf-8 files... they don't deal with single bytes, but single characters. This consisted of several simple re-writings of code, reading and seeking in different patterns.

Thanks to @satuon for your help.